# gdb 'call' returns negative value

Tags: c++, c, gdb, shared-libraries, gnu

I am trying to load a shared library in gdb and invoke entry function call from gdb. 
For example mylib.so has mylibraryEntryPoint() function. 
However, I am getting a negative output. I am curious what does this error code mean.

```
    (gdb) sharedlibrary /usr/home/mylib.so
    Symbols already loaded for /usr/home/mylib.so
    (gdb) call mylibraryEntryPoint()
    $9 = -2048550400    // Here is the problem.
```

The strange part is this function call works on another Linux VM with same gdb version. 
I am expecting the function to be 'executed' on this machine. (It prints some lines as well). Since it is returning the negative value which is not really returned by my function, it is an error code of gdb. It tells gdb was unable to run the function.

Comment: What is the output of `(gdb) ptype mylibraryEntryPoint` and does it match the way you declared it in your source?

Comment: yes it returns int value. 
 (gdb) ptype mylibraryEntryPoint()
type = int

Comment: The return type for your function is `int`, which can be negative.  You might want to extend your question to explain what you are expecting the output to be and why.  The value you're seeing is whatever value your function returned, not something generated by GDB, as such the meaning is defined by your function.

Comment: It seems to be your library. What value do you return? What value did you expect to see?

Comment: I am execting the function to be executed. (It prints some lines as well). Since it is returning negative value it is not really returned by my function, it is an error code of gdb. it tells gdb was unable to run the function.

Comment: That's not how it works.  The value you see is what GDB thinks your function returned after it was called.  I guess depending on architecture GDB could be failing to extract the correct return value (probably unlikely for an int), or maybe there's something weird with the shared library not being loaded correctly, so it's not running the code you thought it was...  I'd try `break mylibraryEntryPoint` then `call mylibraryEntryPoint ()`.  GDB should stop inside your function and you can step through.  If that doesn't work then I'd double check the library has loaded correctly.